# Two almost identical functions at the same level of scope perform differently

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I have this odd problem I can't get my head around:

I have an object with 3 elements in it (that are important to this problem):

```
base_url: 'http://resttest.******.com/v1/',
remind_url: function() { console.log(this.base_url); return this.base_url +'/member/passwordreminder/' },
login_url:  function() { console.log(this.base_url); return this.base_url + '/member/login' },
```

They look like this within the object:

```
app.controllers.login = new Ext.Controller({
/**
 * @cfg url
 * Login request URL
 */
base_url: 'http://resttest.******.com/v1/',
remind_url: function() { console.log(this.base_url); return this.base_url +'/member/passwordreminder/' },
login_url:  function() { console.log(this.base_url); return this.base_url + '/member/login' },
```

When I call remind_url, base_url is equal to what it should be ('http://resttest.******.com/v1/'), however when I call login_url, base_url is undefined.

Why?

Comment: Please do not put tags into the question. There is a separate "tags" field for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that it's a problem with `this`. When `base_url` is undefined, it's probably because `this` is the global object, not your object. Do you have something in there that is binding `remind_url` to `this`? For example, in Backbone.js, views commonly have a line using Underscore.js like this:

```
_.bindAll(this, 'remind_url, 'login_url', etc);
```

which will bind all methods that are getting called as callbacks to `this`.

To confirm this, change `console.log(this.base_url)` to `console.log(this)` to find out what `this` is in this case.

Comment: You are probably right about the reason, but considering one of them already works, this is probably not the right solution.

Comment: I can't answer my own question yet, because I'm too low of a score, but I found the solution to the problem: thanks to Renesis for asking the right question!

I had been treating the call as a method, not as a function - this.login_url = undefined, but this.login_url() is not.

Comment: @Renesis I did say "Do you have something in there that is binding remind_url to `this`?" - I thought maybe that was being bound but the other one wasn't. But that obviously wasn't the solution anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Renesis for asking the right question!

I had been treating the call as a method, not as a function - this.login_url = undefined, but this.login_url() is not.